# Find general equation for the following sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the following sequence: $$a_1 = 1, a_{n+1}=2*a_{n} + 1$$

what is the general equation for $a_n$?
I couldn't find it because the sequence is not in the form of $a_{n+1} = a_n * c$ neither is it
in the form of $a_{n+1} = a_n + c$, but more like a combination of the two.

Comment: @CalvinLin I am sorry, someone edited my question and misinterpreted my equation. I have fixed it now.

Comment: A) Are you familiar with recurrence relations and characteristic equations? B) Alternatively, how about induction? C) Can you list out some initial values to make a guess at the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} &= 2a_{n} + 1 = 2(2a_{n-1}+1) + 1 \\
&= 4a_{n-1} + 2 + 1 = 4(2a_{n-2} + 1) + 2 + 1 \\
&= 8a_{n-2} + 4 + 2 + 1 = ... \\
&= 2^na_1 + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k
\end{align}
$$
Using the formula for the geometric series and using the fact that $a_1 = 1$, we are able to obtain:
$$
\begin{align}
a_{n+1} = 2^na_1 + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} 2^k = 2^na_1 + 2^n-1 = 2^{n+1}-1
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**$a_1 = 1, a _ 2 = 3, a_3 = 7, a_4 = 15, a_5 = 31$.

What does this sequence look like? Can you guess the form?

Can you prove this is the equation for $a_n$ via induction?

---

If you are still stuck, write down what you've tried and where you're stuck at.

Comment: seems like 2^n - 1? But how can I prove it? This is part of an algorithm that later need to be proven

Comment: @avivgood2 Did you read the last line? Or questions A and B in my comment above?

Comment: induction seems like an efficient method for this problem. I will try it

Answer (score 1):

$$a_1 = 1, a_{n+1}=2a_{n} + 1\tag{1}$$
Substitute $n$ with $n+1$
$$a_{n+2}=2a_{n+1}+1;\;a_2=2a_1+1=2+1=3\tag{2}$$
Subtract $(2)-(1)$
$$a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}=2a_{n+1}+1-(2a_{n} + 1)$$
$$a_{n+2}-3a_{n+1}+2a_n=0;\;a_1=1;\;a_2=3$$
solve
$$\lambda^2-3\lambda+2=0\to \lambda=1;\;\lambda=2$$
solutions have the form
$$a_n=a\cdot 1^n+b\cdot 2^n$$
plug the index $n=1,n=2$. Get the system
$$
\begin{cases}
a+2b=1\\
a+4b=3\\
\end{cases}
$$
$a=-1;\;b=1$ is the solution, so the solution of the recurrence is
$$a_n=2^n-1$$

Answer (score 1):

$$a_{n+1}+1=2(a_n+1) \implies a_n+1=2^{n-1}(a_1+1)=2^n \implies a_n=2^n-1$$

It works for any $a_{n+1} = ka_n+b$.

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to solve
$$a_{n+1}=2\,a_{n} + 1$$
Let $a_n=n_n+k$ and replace
$$b_{n+1}+k=2\,b_{n} +2k+ 1$$ If you make $k=2k+1$, that is to say $k=-1$ you have
$$b_{n+1}=2\,b_{n}$$

Solve it and, when done, go back to $a_n$.